# Rails with Paperclip not working in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Paperclip gem in my Rails 5 app and in development everything was OK but in production I no images are shown and in puma log I get error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/articles/images/000/000/003/medium/learn_language.jpg"):
```

and in my app folder when I go to `public/system/articles/images/000/000/003/medium` the image `learn_language.jpg` is there, and I can't figure out the reason why the images are not appearing

Comment: Typo: you mean to say "Paperclip _not_ working in Production" in your title.

Comment: Also, do you have a good reason to use Rails 5 in production? Because if not, you might want to use a stable version.

Comment: It's new project I'm doing so I want to try it out, btw everything was working fine till this issue

Comment: I'd keep with R5 even in beta. Keeps your codebase up to edge

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling the image (`image_tag`)?

Comment: <%= image_tag @articles[0].image.url(:medium) %>

Comment: I tried with rails 4.2.5.1 still it doesn't work, it looks like it's related to produciton environment, still can't get it to work

Answer (score 3):

On Rails 5 (tested on 5.0.0.rc1) if you ran rails without nginx or different proxy server like

```
rails s -e production
```

when for Paperclip you need to set

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

in your `config/environments/production.rb`

Or you could set `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` env variable because by default rails check it

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```